# Is there any difference in meaning and usage between the phrase "judging from" and "going by"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrases

Is there any difference in meaning and usage between the phrase *judging from* and *going by*? For example:

> **Judging from** how you look, you have completely recovered from the illness.
>
> **Going by** how you look, you have completely recovered from the illness.

By the way, do the sentences sound natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning.

The phrase "*judging from*" and the phrase "*going by*" are syntactically different, but semmantically equivilant.

Also, both of the sentences you provided are natural sounding.